# How to check if there exists a certain set of foreign keys in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, join

In mysql, I have a threads table, and a table for threadusers, and each threaduser has its own id and a foreign key to the thread table. Now given a set of user id's, I want to see if there exists a thread with users who are exactly those id's. No more or less people involved. I have this code which seems to work given 2 user id's:

```
    $query = "SELECT th.id
              FROM (
                 SELECT th.id
                 FROM thread th
                 JOIN thread_user tu ON th.id=tu.thread_id AND (tu.user_id={$user_id} OR tu.user_id={$target_id})
                 GROUP BY th.id
                 HAVING count(tu.id)=2
              ) th
              JOIN thread_user tu ON th.id=tu.thread_id
              GROUP BY th.id
              HAVING count(tu.id)=2";
```

The inner subquery gets all threads who's users contains both the given id's. Then I join it with all users for each thread, and group them and filter by 2 again. And the result should be the threads with users who are exactly the given id's, no more or less people.

This seems redundant, is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your table structure correctly you should be able to do it by just querying the link table `thread_user`. Like so

```
SELECT thread_id
FROM thread_user
WHERE id IN (111,222)
GROUP BY thread_id
HAVING COUNT(id) = 2;
```

Comment: This won't work because lets say there are other rows in thread_user with the same thread_id and a different id, then this query would still return that thread_id, whereas I don't want it to return that. This is because the set of foreign keys that exist for the current thread_id should be exactly (111,222), there shouldn't be anymore or less.

Comment: Did you actually try it?

Answer (score -1):

```
Select th.id, count (th.id) 
from thread th 
  inner join thread_user tu on th.id = tu.thread_id 
where tu.user_id in ({$user_id}) 
   OR tu.user_id in ({$target_id}) 
group by (th.id) 
having count (th.id) >= 2
```

The inner join selects only records from both tables that have a matching id. Use in to search for sets $user_id could be comma separated values

Comment: This will only get threads who have at least one of the 2 given users. I want the threads who have exactly both those two people (no more/less).

Comment: Try using group by and having

Comment: This has the same effect.